# GoTo Unreachable Target error during model

Tags: anylogic

I'm running a simulation on a school building on Anylogic PLE version. I used pedGoTo block for Peds (as students) to go to their lockers, using a polygonal area and attractors for each locker. The model runs for a bit but eventually I get the following error:

root.ToLockers.pedGoToTarget:Unreachable target

[Click on this link to see a picture of my area and attractors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOfbh.png)

[Click on this link to see a picture of the error during the simulation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxIxL.png)

(I'm new to stack overflow and for some reason I'm not allowed to embed pictures)

The peds try to go through walls to reach the attractors. I made sure to draw the polygonal area around walls and any object that might be in the way to avoid this but it keeps happening. It happens with a different attractor every time I run the model so it's not just a specific one. The attractors are set to Random.

How can I fix this to avoid peds trying to go through walls?

Comment: show picture to check

Comment: Hi Felipe, I just added pictures to my post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear form the image but my advice would be to try some more debugging of reachability using the following method:

1. Use the same layout
2. Create a separate flow where an agent is injected at a random point on the layout
3. Make the agent attempt to reach that location

There can be two outcomes:

1. The point is unreachable from anywhere - meaning that a mistake was made in drawing the layout at the destination (locker) location
2. The point is unreachable from some locations - meaning that there are issues with pathfinding in which case it is advisable to create intermediate points that should be reached before targeting final destination (locker)